# Huggingface not saving model checkpoint

Tags: nlp, bert, gpt, huggingface, t5

I am trying to train T5 model. This is how my training arguments look like:

```
args = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(
    model_dir,
    evaluation_strategy="steps",
    eval_steps=100,
    logging_strategy="steps",
    logging_steps=100,
    save_strategy="steps",
    save_steps=200,
    learning_rate=4e-5,
    per_device_train_batch_size=batch_size,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=batch_size,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    save_total_limit=3,
    num_train_epochs=10,
    predict_with_generate=True,
    fp16=True,
    load_best_model_at_end=True,
    metric_for_best_model="rouge1",
    report_to="tensorboard"
)
```

My model trained for 7600 steps. But the last model saved was for checkpoint 1800:

[image]

Why is this so?